# Passing argument to same button and checking the argument in function with if condition

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons that use the same function, I need to be able to identify which button I pressed.

On button 1 I put `onclick="myFunction(1)"` and on button 2 I put `myFunction(2)` then on `myFunction(a)` if I use if condition `a=1` it won't execute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
<!-- CSR -->
<label onclick="myFunction(a.value=1)">CSR</label>
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="CSRNm"><br>
    
<!-- Acct# -->
<label onclick="myFunction(a.value=2)">Acct#</label>
<input type="text" value="Hello Other World" id="AccNo">
    
<script>
function myFunction(a) {  
  if (a.value=1){
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(CSRNm.value);
    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("Copied the text: " + a.value);
  } else if (a.value=2){
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(AccNo.value);
    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("Copied the text: " + AccNo.value);
  }  
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing `a.value` just pass it as `a` as follows:

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction(a=1)">one</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="myFunction(a=2)">two</button>
```

```js
const myFunction = (a) => {
    if (a === 1) {
        console.log("a");
    }
    if (a === 2) {
        console.log("b");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I'm really really just starting out, I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Next time try to add supporting code snippet and to do debug and go through documentation first. All in all [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is sufficient to understand each and every function, element, api in vanilla websites. So try to take full advantage of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
myFunction(a.value=1)
```

you can use this:

```
myFunction({value: 1})
```

The function declaration for `myFunction` *already* refers to the parameter as `a`.

So, when you pass the object literal `{value: 1}` as the function parameter, the executing function will return `1` when asked for `a.value`.